# UnsatisfiedDependencyException after adding dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, datasource, pom.xml

Hi i have added dependencies and ojdbc in path but still getting UnsatisfiesDependencyexception.

Dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId> oracle </groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/ojdbc6.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

I placed ojdbc6.jar in src/main/resources

Interface ADAO

```
public interface ADao{
 A membershipFromxUsernameActive( String xUsername);
}
```

Interface ARepo

```
public interface ARepository extends Repository{

 @Query(value="SELECT m FROM A m where lower(m.x) = lower(:key) AND m.y='ACT'",nativeQuery=true)
    A fetchADetails(@Param("key") String key);
```

}

Error
Even I searched many sites soulution was given but i did not worked for me.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [OracleConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection Caching Not Enabled or Not a Valid Cache Enabled DataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource  Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connection Caching Not Enabled or Not a Valid Cache Enabled DataSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
```

Comment: post your application.property content

Comment: ...and also `OracleConfiguration`

Comment: Use `${basedir}` instead of `${project.basedir}`

Comment: #Oracle connection
oracle.username=root
oracle.password=xxx
oracle.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xyz.amazonaws.com:1521/ABC



spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

Comment: @Ubercool It did not worked sorry

Comment: *Connection Caching Not Enabled or Not a Valid Cache Enabled DataSource* - This is clearly not a dependency issue. Check [Configuring Spring Boot for Oracle](https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-oracle/)

Comment: @Autowired DataSource in service solved the issue....thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding 
@Autowired 
DataSource database;
in service solved this issue.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like datasource caching must be enabled first before starting spring boot , try adding these properties in your config

mentioned here - https://community.oracle.com/thread/867795

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) - ***Provide context for links***: *Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there.* ***Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.***